# Dual boot ubuntu unknows hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

i have a windows 7 and want to install ubuntu alongside. i have 2 hardrives
1 is for windows 7 and the second one is too but just for some files (movies, music,...) the second one is bigger, so i shrinked it with windows program (200gb). got ubuntu cd burned and tried to install it. when clicking something else for partitions, this is where i get the problem. 1st hardrive its shown no problem. but the second one shows his full capacity 1500gb but not partitions.
i have 3 partitions  (900 gb and 300 gb for windows) and 200gb unallocated.
as it shows whole hardrive, its type is unknown. what can i do?

Comment: Is it really 4 partitions? post this `sudo parted -l` With MBR you can only have 4 primary partitions, so installer fails. Also could be NTFS needs chkdsk, or several other possibilities.

Comment: be sure the INstaller is booting in EFI mode.